# How To Use Dexdump

Tags: android

I want to use the command "dexdump" to see a .dex in the .txt,but in the command line, it says:"dexdump:command not found",why?And Is there another way to use the command "dexdump"?

Comment: This question concerns a program which ships with the Android SDK - so it is both explicitly on-topic as a development tool question, and not in any way a search for code, as it is part of the standard tool suite for the platform in question.

Answer (score 5):

`dexdump` should be located in a version-specific folder under the `build-tools/` folder of your Android sdk installation - at least if the latter is *fully* installed (ie, you can build and run apps).

If you run the program without arguments it will print out some usage help, but presumably you are asking this because you found a suggestion somewhere to use it which gives you some idea of the command line you would use.

Answer (score 0):

`dexdump` is installed as a build-tool, it is not available across env path by default (you will add it but it is linked to an specific version).

I use it with:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/dexdump classes2.dex
```

Comment: Mine is at `/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/29.0.2/dexdump`. I found it using `locate dexdump`.