# How to decompile phone app back to kotlin code?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, decompiling

I recently I lost all of my app's files, but luckly I still had my app saved on my phone. I extracted the app on pc, but I am not sure what to do next.
App was written in kotlin and I would like to decompile the app to it, so I could modify the app later in Android Studio.

The screenshot shows all the files which I have now. I am really thankful for all advices.

[image]

Comment: I would be a little surprised if a Kotlin decompiler existed yet?  You could probably turn it into Java.

Answer (score 1):

this is 100% a fine example of why you should use source tracking with git or something similar, and there's no reason to not do so, because it's free unless your business is huge.

those are .dex files.  There's a tool in the android sdk called dexdump that can decode them.  Your mileage may vary on how well it works though, and it's almost certainly going to mix java and kotlin code.

A version of this program exists for each sdk you have downloaded, and it is specific for it.  For info on locating it, look here:
[How To Use Dexdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899033/how-to-use-dexdump)

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain to me how to dexdump these files? I mean I already tried to do it but cmd shows me errors as I the screenshot.
Firstly I tried to dexdump zip and then just folder, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is the screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16UlLCXLt2EQ94TXkPdTZTnXcsFKFOMZt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it works on individual files with .dex extensions.  More than that i can't help you.

Comment: I tried dexdump on individual dex files, but I get this error:

Processing 'C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\lifer\classes7.dex'...
E/dalvikvm( 8780): ERROR: unsupported dex version (30 33 39 00)
E/dalvikvm( 8780): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
ERROR: Failed structural verification of 'C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\lifer\classes7.dex'

Do you maybe know how to solve this?

Comment: unsupported dex version implies you are using the wrong version of dexdump.  You have multiple copies of this tool installed that are each designed for a specific framework.   If you don't know which one you used, you'll have to try all versions of dexdump you have installed.